# Hide the chart's series in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

I'm migrating ExtJs 3 application to ExtJs 4. One of the component that I need to change is a chart that has series of bars and lines on it. It displays the data for previous and current years. Beside the chart there is a checkbox "Compare to previous year". When it checked all line series should be visible and hidden when it is not checked.
In ExtJs 3 I did this task by setting visibility:hidden for series styles this way: chart.setSeriesStyles(...). But in ExtJs 4 this function is absent and I can't find any other way to hide series on demand.
Here is the code of my chart:

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [
        'month','data1','data2','data3','prev_data1','prev_data2','prev_data3'
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/getmonthlystats.php'
    }
});

this.statChart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    flex: 1,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 100,
        fields: [
            'data1',
            'data2',
            'data3',
            'prev_data1',
            'prev_data2',
            'prev_data3'
        ],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        grid: true
    },{
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['month'],
        label: {
            rotate: {
                degrees: 315
            }
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        yField: ['data1','data2','data3'],
        xField: 'month'
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        yField: 'prev_data1',
        xField: 'month'
    },{
        type: 'line',
        yField: 'prev_data2',
        xField: 'month'
    },{
        type: 'line',
        yField: 'prev_data3',
        xField: 'month'
    }]
});
```

So, the lines prev_data1, prev_data2, prev_data3 should be shown or hidden when needed (depending on the checkbox state). Does anyone know the way to do that?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (sample from my code):

```
handler: function (checkbox, checked) {
    if (checked)
        chart.series.getAt(index).showAll();
    else
        chart.series.getAt(index).hideAll();
}
```

Comment: it hides lines, but all dots that indicates peaks of line charts are still shown.

Comment: well, it works in 4.0.2, not sure about other versions. Try to look  the series source code.

Comment: I set showMarkers:false for line series to hide markers at all. That's ok for me. Other solution would be completely recreate chart with new series config.

Answer (score 0):

For ExtJS 4.2.x

If you use 'legend' with your charts, this code will be better for you:

```
var chart = Ext.getCmp(chartId);
var series = chart.series.getAt(seriesIndex);
if (value) {
    series.showInLegend = true;
    series.showAll();
} else {
    series.showInLegend = false;
    series.hideAll();
}
chart.redraw();
```